# Escape unicode escaping in Java

Tags: java, unicode, escaping, javadoc, unicode-escapes

I'm writing Javadoc for a class explaining proper unicode escaping:

```
 * String unitAbbrev = "μs"; //Best: perfectly clear even without a comment.
 * String unitAbbrev = "\u03bcs"; //Poor: the reader has no idea what this is.
```

Unfortunately they both render with "μs":

[image]

**Is there any way to escape this unicode escape?**

Double backslash (`"\\u03bcs"`) doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the escaped Unicode literal for the backslash itself, I think:

\u005c

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Javadoc renders perfectly, but I loose readability without rendering (`\u005cu03bcs`) and my code still uses escaped Unicode literals with trigger style violations. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest, is to play with the {@literal  text} syntax. But I'm not sure if this affects unicode as I haven't tried it... Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use the HTML escape `&#92;`, which still isn't *great* when read from source, but it's at least clearly *not* a unicode escape.

The only disadvantage of HTML escapes is they don't work inside `{@code ...}` blocks (they're rendered verbatim), so you need to use `<pre>` and `<code>` instead.

It seems like `\\` *should* work as `javac` appears to handle it correctly, but `javadoc` isn't.